# Variable access from Scriptlet tag to declaration tag in JSP

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

Hi I am declaring user agent in Scriptlet tag and I am not able to access that user       agent in declarative tag I have tried the following code:

```
<%
    String ua = request.getHeader( "User-Agent" );
    boolean isSafari=(ua != null && ua.indexOf("Safari") != -1);
%>
```

I access this `isSafari` in declarative tag like this`<%! if(isSafari){} %>`

Here I am able to get user agent of browser
but when I am using it in declarative tag it say variable `isSafari` not found please declare.

Comment: <%String ua = request.getHeader( "User-Agent" ); boolean isSafari=( ua != null && ua.indexOf( "Safari" ) != -1 );%> i am access this  isSafari in declarative tag like this<%! if(isSafari){} %> its saying variable isSafari not declared

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a declarative tag at all.  Get rid of the `!` and make sure to put something in the `{}` of the if-statement, and it will work fine.

```
 <%
 String ua = request.getHeader( "User-Agent" ); 
 boolean isSafari=( ua != null && ua.indexOf( "Safari" ) != -1 );
 %> 
 blah blah blah
 <% if(isSafari){ %>
 some html code here
 <% } %>
 or
 <% if(isSafari)
 {
    out.print("some html code");
 }
 %>
```

Second, the purpose of a declarative tag, as the name implies, is to *declare* things, not to use them.  So you could have done this

```
 <%!
 String ua = null;
 boolean isSafari = false; 
 %> 
 blah blah blah
 <%
   ua = request.getHeader( "User-Agent" ); 
   isSafari = ( ua != null && ua.indexOf( "Safari" ) != -1 );
   if(isSafari)
   {
     out.print("some html code");
   }
 %>
```

Mostly a declarative tag would be used for declaring functions, actually.  But its not advised to put a bunch of code in your JSP these days (see [JSP info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)) so you really should not be defining functions in your JSPs.